# Issue with storing items in session in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a customer page on which user can enter multiple locations for customer. I am using telerik ajax grid to display locations, and  when a new location is added, I am adding it to session and returning back to the grid. Finally, when user submits, customer and all locations using customerid as reference key gets inserted. I am clearing the session, when user enters create/edit page and on successful commit or any exception occurs. Problem is when user adds the locations for one user and then opens another tab, to create another user then all locations get cleared for previous user. Because of session, this issue is occuring. Something of viewstate would be page specific. But for ajax grid actions, viewdata/viewbag is not working. Any thoughts on how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the customerID you currently work on in a route value.

Have a list of customers. In the list have a link for each customer that has the form

```
/{controller}/{action}/{id}

/customer/edit/1
```

Telerik Controls doesnt help you here. Its easier to start with a plain loop that renders the customers in the view.

Comment: yes I am new to asp.net mvc. I was comparing viewbag/viewdata with viewstate in webforms. But I realized they are not the same, we need to fill them each time in MVC. I am good with displaying customers and create/edit customer as well. Problem here is I have only one save button on the page and multiple locations can be added on the customer page. I need to store locations temporarily untill save button is clicked. For that I used session, but problem is when user uses browser tabs.

Comment: Try to hold the list of locations in the UI by writing out arrays of form fields. This article might get you started http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Yes, seems that I can either generate strongly typed array client side and post to the page (or) store values using random generated guid in session.